# Solving Laplace's equation using mean value property

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let we have a problem:
$$ \min \big\{\int_B |\nabla u|^2 dx: \ u\in\mathcal{C}^2(\bar B,\mathbb{R}^2), u|_{\partial B}=x \big\}
$$
which is equivalent to solve the Laplace's equation
$$
 \begin{cases}
  -\Delta u (x)=0 \\
  u|_{\partial B}=x
 \end{cases}
$$
My question here is - can we apply the Mean Value property of the harmonic functions to obtain the solution using the boundary condition? I am not sure how to work it out.

$$
u(x)=\def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_{\partial B} u(y)\,d\sigma(y)=\def\avint{\mathop{\,\rlap{-}\!\!\int}\nolimits} \avint_{\partial B} y\,d\sigma(y)
$$

Comment: That integral would give you the value of $u$ at $0$.

Comment: I don't understand, why at $0$?

Comment: Because $0$ is the center of the sphere. The mean value property tells you that the value at the center equals the mean on the sphere.

Comment: Any by the way, the integral is $0$. Here I am always assuming that the sphere is centered at the origin.

Comment: hence from mean value property we can deduce only that $u(0)=0$ and I don't see how together with the boundary conditions it can give the solution, therefore I suppose that this is not a possible way to solve?

Comment: Exactly. There are other methods to solve that, though. Try looking for "Poisson kernel".

Comment: I appreciate your help, Giuseppe

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I think that the affine function will minimize this functional (I found one lemma in my notes which states that if the minimizer if affine then it minimizes the $\int_A f(\nabla u)dA$ where $f$ is convex and continuous), therefore together with the boundary conditions and the mean value property we can conclude that the identity $(u^1,u^2)=(x_1,x_2)$ satisfies our minimization problem (taking in the consideration that the solution of the Dirichlet problem is unique)

Comment: Yes. Right. It is actually even simpler. It is clear that $-\Delta x=(-\Delta x_1, -\Delta x_2)=(0,0).$ So $x$ is a solution to the PDE. It is obvious that $x$ satisfies the boundary condition. Conclusion $x$ is a solution to the boundary value problem. Now, that boundary value problem has only one solution. Therefore $x$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We made some progress on this question in the comments. We reached the conclusion that the mean value property can only be used to obtain the value of $u$ at the center of the ball $B$. If such center is at $0$, then
$$
u(0)=\frac{1}{\lvert\partial B\rvert}\int_{\partial B}y\, d\sigma(y)=0, $$
and the integral vanishes by symmetry (it turns into $-$ itself under the transformation $y\mapsto -y$).